# How do I find index of value in List<IGrouping<string, XElement>>?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq

I have an XML and it contains multiple sections. Many of which may or may not be repeated. I have grouped the sections and got a `List<IGrouping<string, XElement>>` variable.

Now, I want to find the index of a string in this list and print it, but every time I am running the loop, it is always 0.

Following is my code:

```
//body contains the descendants of the main XML.    
List<IGrouping<string, XElement>> sectionlist = body.Descendants("sec").GroupBy(b => b.Element("title").Value).Select(b => b).ToList();

//Here, I want to find the index of uniquesections.Key in the list. "sectionlist"
foreach (var uniquesections in sectionlist)
{
   string uniquesectionskey = uniquesections.Key;
   var indesxofstring = sectionlist.FindIndex(el => sectionlist.ElementAt(sectionkey).Key == uniquesectionskey);
   sectionkey++;
}
```

Please help.

Regards
Aman

Comment: Your FindIndex query in the loop using `sectionlist.ElementAt(sectionkey)` doesn't really make much sense... why do you use FindIndex with an unused lambda argument `el` if all you do is comparing `sectionlist.ElementAt(sectionkey).Key` for each loop iteration?

Comment: In other words, your FindIndex code is like doing this `bool b = sectionlist.ElementAt(sectionkey).Key == uniquesectionskey;` followed by `var indesxofstring = sectionlist.FindIndex(el => b);`. So, depending on the value of `b`, FindIndex in your code can only ever return 0 or -1. Try to understand this behavior of your code.

Comment: I got your point, but I have to use FindIndex to get the index of the string value that I am searching for in the list. What change shall I make in order to get the desired output?